# How to initialize Custom control attribute (property) of complex type (struct\ class)

Tags: c#, asp.net, initialization, custom-controls

I have a custom control in asp.net
My custom control have a class member of type Size (value type with Width and Height inner members).
I would like to initialize this member from the .aspx file.

The ideal solution will be (this line will not pass compilation):

```
<CustomControl:MyCtrl runat="server" ID="MyCtrlID" MaxSize="{Width=200, Height=400}"/>
```

The code at the .cs file:

```
public partial class MyCtrl: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public System.Drawing.Size MaxSize { get; set;}

    // Class logic...
}
```

Of curse I can solve this issue by adding logic to the setter (at the c# code), like this:

```
private System.Drawing.Size m_MaxSize;
public string MaxSize 
{ 
    set 
    { 
        string[] sizes = value.Split(",");
        m_MaxSize.Width = sizes[0];
        m_MaxSize.Height = sizes[1];
    }
}
```

But do we have any asp.net syntax to do this for us?, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Size Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses [SizeConverter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.sizeconverter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to convert and access `Size` properties, the following example demonstrates how to properly delcare `MaxSize` property:

```
<CustomControl:MyCtrl runat="server" ID="MyCtrlID" MaxSize="200, 400"/>
```

**About Type Converters**

Type Converters

> provides a unified way of converting types of values to other types,
>   as well as for accessing standard values and subproperties.

ASP.NET uses type converters at run time to serialize and deserialize objects stored in control state and in view state, follow [Type Converter Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87926x56(v=vs.140).aspx) for a more details.